# what does setState: function(){ mean

Tags: javascript

what does it mean when you set a function like this

```
setState: function(){  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is incomplete, but it looks like you're assigning a function as the value to a property called `setState` of an object that isn't shown in your code.

An example:

```
var myObject = {
    prop1: 'abc',
    prop2: function() {
       alert('def');
    }
};
```

Above, I'm creating a variable called `myObject` that is an object with two properties, `prop1` and `prop2`. The first one is a string. If I write `alert(myObject.prop1)` it'll alert "abc".

The second one is a function. If I write `myObject.prop2()` I'll execute that function, which'll alert "def".

Answer (score 2):

That would appear in the context of an *object literal*, like this:

```
var obj = {
    setState: function(){  
    }
};
```

It assigns the function to the named property of the object. The function is anonymous (it has no name), though the property has a name. You could call the function like so:

```
obj.setState();
```

Literal notation is basically a series of `propname: value` within curly braces (`{}`), separated by commas, where `value` can be any valid value —a string, a number, a function reference... The property name can appear literally, as in your example, or in quotes (`"propname": value`) if the literal name is a reserved word (e.g., you'd need quotes for a property called `var` since `var` is a reserved word).